# Express the volume as a function of the height

Tags: volume

A conical cup is 9 inches high and its radius across the top is 2 inches. If the cup contains liquid, express the volume of the liquid as a function of the height of the liquid.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Volume= $\pi  \ \ r^{2} h/3$

So in your case, $ V= \pi  \ (r^{2}) h/3$

$f(h) =  4 ( \pi)  h/3$

Comment: Was that liquid very alcoholic?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if two solids are similar and their similarity ratio is $a$, then their volumes are in the ratio of $a^3$.

Comment: Hint: one of solids is fluid. And another one is (partially) hollow...